# Creating a proof and finding the real roots of unknown function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, solution-verification, roots, alternative-proof

> The curve of the function $f (x)$ is given.
>
> [image]
>
> Find the real roots of the equation $f (4-3x^2)=0.$

I know the possible solution:

> From  the equations $4-3x^2=-2$  and  $4-3x^2=4$ we have $ x=\left\{0,\sqrt 2,- \sqrt 2\right\} $.

Now, I want to create a little proof for the alternative solution before moving on to the calculation.

It is obvious that, we don't know directly what the explicit form of $f(x)$ is.

**Goal:**  I want to find a new $ g (4-3x ^ 2) = 0 $ equation that will definitely give the same real solutions as the equation $f (4-3x ^ 2) = 0.$

> Let's define the function $g:\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow \mathbb {R}$.
>
> For any $x\in\mathbb {R}$ if $f(x)=0$, then $g(x)=0$ and if $f(x)≠0$, then $g(x)≠0$ and there exist at least one $x=r, r\in \mathbb{R}$, which gives $f(r)≠g(r)$.
>
> According to our definition of $g(x)$, we deduce that for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$, if  $f(4-3x^2)=0,$ then $g(4-3x^2)=0$  and if  $f(4-3x^2)≠0,$ then $g(4-3x^2)≠0.$
>
> Finally, we can deduce that solving the equation $ f (4-3x ^ 2) = 0 $ is equivalent to solving the equation $ g (4-3x ^ 2) = 0. $
> In other words, the real roots of the equation $ f (4-3x^2) = 0 $ are the same as the equation $ g (4-3x^2) = 0$. So, it is enough to solve the equation  $g (4-3x^2) = 0$.

> Let, $g(x)=(x+2)(x-4)$.
>
> Then we have, $$g(4-3x^2)=0 \Longrightarrow  (4-3x^2+2)(4-3x^2-4)=0 \Longrightarrow -3x^2(6-3x^2)=0 \Longrightarrow x=\left\{0,\sqrt 2,- \sqrt 2\right\} $$

Question: Is my proof-solution correct?

Comment: From the graph we have$$f(4-3x^2)=0\iff 4-3x^2\in\{-2,4\}$$

Comment: You seem to have come to the correct conclusion though maybe with a little too much work, and your answer looks right!

Comment: I don't see why you need $g$

Comment: I'm not sure if we can assume, from the figure, that there are only two roots of $f(x)=0$. If we can assume so, then all we need is to solve $4-3x^2=-2,4$ giving $x=0,\pm\sqrt 2$. If we cannot assume so, the question is not solvable. In my opinion, the point in the problem is whether we can assume so or not, not whether $f(x)$ is a parabola or not. As to your solution, I cannot see why you can have $g(x)=(x+2)(x-4)$, and in the first place I don't see why you need $g$ either.

Comment: @mathlove Thank you so much for commenting.  I want to say what I did. Yes, you are right. We accept we have only $2$ roots.  I want to give a little example. For example $f(x)=x^x-2$ and $g(x)=x-r_1$ where $r_1$ is the root of $f(x)$. So, we have $f(r_1)=g(r_1)=0$ but, $f(x)≠g(x)$ Where, $x≠r_1$. I just wanted to produce an alternative solution. I mean we have completely different $2$ functions but the roots are the same.